# How to move a view on touch in Kotlin

Tags: android, button, kotlin

I want to move a button view whenever it is touched from the center position in a Relative Layout parent to positions such as top-right etc. How to do this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this method ,It is a example as you didn't provide any code:

```
   class YourMainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // Hide the action bar
        val actionBar = supportActionBar

        actionBar!!.hide()

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shapes_view)

      var listener = View.OnTouchListener(function = {view, motionEvent ->

            if (motionEvent.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

                view.y = motionEvent.rawY - view.height/2
                view.x = motionEvent.rawX - view.width/2
            }

            true

        })

        // Declared in our activity_shapes_view.xml file.
        draggableImage.setOnTouchListener(listener)

    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
private enum class GestureMode { NONE, DRAG, ZOOM, ROTATION }
private var gestureMode = GestureMode.NONE
private var any_view? = null

any_view.setOnTouchListener(initTouchListener(id))

private fun initTouchListener(id: String): OnTouchListener {
        var dX = 0f
        var dY = 0f
        var _x = 0f
        var _y = 0f

        return OnTouchListener(function = { view, event ->
            //Log.d("1111", "gesture Mode : $gestureMode")



            when (event.action) {

                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    gestureMode = GestureMode.DRAG

                    dX = view.x - event.rawX
                    dY = view.y - event.rawY
                }

                MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                    if (gestureMode == GestureMode.DRAG) {
                        _x = event.rawX + dX
                        _y = event.rawY + dY
                        moveTheView(view, _x, _y)
                   }
                }

                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                   gestureMode = GestureMode.NONE
                }
            }
            true
        })
    }


    private fun moveTheView(view: View?, _x: Float, _y: Float) {
        view!!.animate()
            .x(_x)
            .y(_y)
            .setDuration(0)
            .start()

        view.invalidate()
    }
```